# Oracle working with UNIX timestamp

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, session, unix-timestamp

I have a sessiondata table with session data from Zend_Auth_Db.

I want to run an Oracle procedure every 30 seconds to check if the MODIFIED field in the table hasn't been updated in the last 120 seconds. I have this Query below which should work but it's not returning the right results?

`SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA WHERE MODIFIED < ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400)) - 120;`

Anyone know how I can modify that query to return the correct results?

DB table set up:

[image]

Comment: What are the right results, and what does it return instead? Running that query against that data returns the row you show. Are you sure you mean you want to check that it *hasn't* been updated - might make more sense to be checking for data that *has* changed (i.e. change the `<` to a `>`), but I'm really not sure what the problem is at the moment.

Comment: I want the query to return any results where the modified field hasn't been modified in the last 120 seconds :)

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't want a row to be returned if the date modified field hasn't been "modified" in the last 120 seconds :)

Comment: But that's what it seems to be doing - if I create a sessiondata table with modified set to 1361814865, your query returns that row. So I'm missing something. Is this a timezone issue maybe? That timestamp is `2013-02-25 17:54:25`, which for me (in the UK) is in the past; maybe it isn't yet for you?

Comment: You may be on to something there Alex, I'm in the UK also, this is zend stamping the session :S

Comment: Your last two comments are contradictory, surely? If you don't want to get a row if it hasn't been modified in the last 120 seconds, then you *do* want to see it if it has, therefore if modified is *greater than*  `sysdate` - 120 seconds... no? Showing the expected results and what you actually get would still make this clearer. Should your query return the row you showed, or not?

Comment: Yeah I think I am confusing myself, the last comment of yours makes sense but is that what I am doing in my query (I thought I was) or is there a better way to write that query?

Comment: If you **don't** expect that row to be returned, because it *hasn't* been modified recently (since it's from yesterday), then your query should just use `>` instead of `<`. I still don't know if that's what you want. Please show more data and expected results, guesswork isn't helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM SESSIONDATA WHERE MODIFIED BETWEEN (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400) - 120 AND (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to return any rows where modified hasn't been "modified" in the last 120 seconds :/

Answer (score 0):

The server with the Oracle DB was a couple of minutes ahead of my server where my app was hosted. So there was an odd roughly 165 second difference between the two so it would not return the proper results. To over come this issues I created a trigger that would update the MODIFIED field to sysdate before each update:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER "TR_UPDATE_MODIFIED" 
  before update on SESSIONDATA
   for each row
    begin
     select (SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400) into :new.MODIFIED       from dual;
end;
```

This ensured that the epoch time stamp matched the SYSDATE in the comparison.